# Register a custom org.osgi.resource.Resource

Tags: java, osgi

How can I register my own OSGi-resource (*org.osgi.resource .Resource*, not a file in a bundle), which can define capabilities and requirements.

I know, that I can define some in the manifest of a bundle. But I want to define some at runtime.

My use-case: I want to write a bunch of bundles for different environments (hardware, OS, configurations). Each bundle should be started if its requirements are met, only. Now, I want to build a Environment-detection-bundle, which runs several more or less complex checks against the environment and then provides the corresponding capabilities.
My goal is, that bundles matching their environment are started, only.

I spend a lot of time, but I didn't find a way to register resources other than bundles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is use capabilities and requirements. You can invent your own [capability namespace](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/resource/Namespace.html) and then have your bundles require it via the [Require-Capability](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#REQUIRE_CAPABILITY) manifest header. You can configure the framework instance to provide the appropriate capability via the [org.osgi.framework.system.capabilities.extra](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMCAPABILITIES_EXTRA) framework launch property depending upon the runtime environment.